# Is it possible to hot swap ionic code in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I’m not sure if I’m using the right terms here but I mean: can I update an app that’s installed on people’s iPhones without asking them to actually update the app?

With my current setup I’m assuming this is not possible, as I’m using ng build and packaging everything up. But wouldn’t it make a lot of sense to be able to serve my app from something like firebase and have the web view on the native app just talk to that server? If that IS possible, how’s it done? Are there drawbacks?

*Context: Ionic4 on Angular. Intend to put out apps for Android and iOS*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/deploy/intro

This will let you push updates without going through the app/play store release process.